# Remove inputs fields dynamically

Tags: jquery

I guess this question has been asked before but I can't find the answer on the forums. I have a form with a question and a 5 possible answers. If the user wants to add an answer, he clicks on "Add an answer." This works fine.

However, when the user adds all the possible responses and decides to cancel reply 4, then add a response, the response counter no longer follows and there can be many times the answer 5.

How to either always chronological order is respected?

The HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
 <form class="form-horizontal left-label">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Question</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:40px;">
                <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Answer 1</label>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Answer 2</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]">
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                 <a class="btn btn-med gray-bg add_field_button" href="#">Add an answer</a> <span class="rep_possible"></span>
             </div>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
```

And the javascript

```
var max_fields      = 3;
var wrapper         = $('.input_fields_wrap');
var add_button      = $('.add_field_button');

var x = 0;
$('.rep_possible').html('Encore ' + (x+3));
$(add_button).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){
        x++;
        if (max_fields-x == 0) {
            $('.add_field_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.rep_possible').html('5 réponses maximum');
        } else {
            $('.rep_possible').html('Encore ' + (max_fields-x));
        }
        wrapper.append('<div class="form-group" data-option="' + (x+2) + '"><label class="control-label col-lg-2">Réponse ' + (x+2) + '</label><div class="col-lg-5"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="mytext[]"></div><div class="col-lg-1"><a class="btn btn-med btn-danger remove_field" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Supprimer cette réponse" title="Supprimer cette réponse" href="#">X</a></div></div>');
    }
});

wrapper.on("click",".remove_field", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().closest('.form-group').remove();
    x--;
    if (max_fields-x != 0) {
        $('.add_field_button').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.rep_possible').html('Encore ' + (max_fields-x));
    }
});
```

Please find the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qLr5huLw/)

A good summary with a picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-number your answers after you delete one.

I wrapped the answer number in a `span`

```
<span class="counter"><span>
```

and then changed your add and remove handlers to call the following function

```
function reNumberAnswers(){
 wrapper.find('.form-group[data-option]').each(function(index){
       var self = $(this);
        self.attr('data-option', index + 3)
            .find('.counter').text(index + 3);
    });
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qLr5huLw/3/

Answer (score 1):

Well you could modify your remove-function:

```
var $formGroup = $(this).parent().closest('.form-group'),
    $siblings = $formGroup.siblings('.form-group.added');
$formGroup.remove();
$siblings.each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1,
        $label = $(this).find('label.control-label'),
        labelValNew = $label.text().replace(/\d/, index);
    $label.text(labelValNew);
});
```

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLr5huLw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLr5huLw/1/) 
Add an extra class name to your answer divs
and always remove the last answer.

```
<div class="form-group answer" data-option="' + (x+2) + '">
```

`$('.answer:last').remove();`

Otherwise you'll have to loop over the answers and redraw them with the correct value.

Alternative you could take a look at [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) or [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) and use an observable.

Comment: Hi, this is better, but it is not what I'm looking for. Indeed, if the user add "answer 5" and decides to delete answer 4, this is answer 5 who will be deleted...